# Embedded report with dynamic RLS throwing 503 error while static RLS works perfectly

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am working on a POC for a project, and I created a report using the Financial sheet provided by powerbi to test dynamic RLS integration at first I went with service principal and then switched to master user authentication for the sake of experimentation, taking into consideration both the service principal and the user are admins on the target workspace.

With static RLS everything loads perfectly, while using dynamic RLS the frame loads but the data doesn't throwing this error:

```
Underlying Error: PowerBI service client received error HTTP response. HttpStatus: 503. PowerBIErrorCode: OpenConnectionError
OpenConnectionError: Failed to open the MSOLAP connection.
Correlation ID: 3c061f0d-ab8a-ec5e-dd96-d6b69e160fdd
Activity ID: f2ed4a55-ebe1-458b-a9d7-c445b4177f2f
Request ID: c0a6e163-7cd0-7fe8-8ded-1e1c46bc3add
Time: Wed Jun 07 2023 14:13:05 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
Service version: 13.0.20819.75
Client version: 2305.5.14128-train
Cluster URI: https://WABI-WEST-EUROPE-E-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: f2ed4a55-ebe1-458b-a9d7-c445b4177f2f
Request ID: c0a6e163-7cd0-7fe8-8ded-1e1c46bc3add
Time: Wed Jun 07 2023 14:13:05 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
Service version: 13.0.20819.75
Client version: 2305.5.14128-train
Cluster URI: https://WABI-WEST-EUROPE-E-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
```

Token generation, and embed URL fetching are successful through powerbi api.

The same problem happens within the Powerbi sandbox, am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure roles are defined properly while generating Embed Token. We will face this error, mostly because of incorrect defined roles ( Faced the same error even if there is a extra space while passing role) .

If the issue still persists, you need to provide more information, on how roles defined and used while generating Embed token.

Refer [Embed a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls) with RLS documentation for more details.